# Error Handler For Server Instance using Jetty9 Ioc

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jetty-9

I have been trying to setup a jetty server with common error handling. I'm using jetty 9.4.44.v20210927 home distribution. As per the [jetty-9 doc](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#custom-error-pages), i have written a class that extends `ErrorHandler` class and overrides the `handle()` method. I exported it as a jar and included it in lib/ext and the class is being discovered and loaded properly (verified using `--debug` and `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG` flags). I've also added this to jetty.xml server instance as instructed in the doc. No matter what change is done, the error is only being handed by the default ErrorPageErrorHandler and not my custom class. This is the xml context file that i have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    ...
    <Call name="addBean">
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.example.test.CustomErrorHandler"/>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
    ...
</Configure>
```

NOTE : I'm trying to set the errorHandler for the entire server instance and not for a specific context. Setting the same error handler for a single context works. But the same does not work for server instance. Also, i'm trying to achieve this using jetty IoC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `Server.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler)`

See: https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.45.v20220203/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#setErrorHandler(org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler)

So that means ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
 "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    ...
    <Set name="errorHandler">
      <New class="com.example.test.CustomErrorHandler"/>
    </Set>
    ...
</Configure>
```

This server level `ErrorHandler` is used for non-webapp based requests, or even requests that have an error that cannot be dispatched to a webapp.

Each Web App will have it's own unique `ErrorPageErrorHandler`, created at the time when the Web App is being deployed.

Comment: Ok. But according to the docs, 

"An ErrorHandler instance may be set on the entire server by setting it as a dependent bean on the Server instance. This can be done by calling Server.addBean(Object) via embedded code or in jetty.xml IoC XML"

wouldn't adding it to Server.addBean alone be enough.

Comment: Also, i tried setting errorHandler as you've said but still, the default ErrorPageErrorHandler is used. Only setting it in WebAppContext seems to work

Comment: Also, there's a small typo in the answer. The <Set> is closed with </Call>.

Comment: `ErrorPageErrorHandler` is unique for each `WebAppContext`, it cannot be standardized at the server level.

Comment: Sure. I understand that it's unique to WebAppContext. But my class extends ErrorHandler and i override the handle() method. That should would work in Server level right ?

Comment: It does work at the server level, for non webapp cases. which there are many.

Comment: Hi. I think i understand now. Before closing this, can you please give some example cases where this server level ErrorHandler will be used ? i.e what non webapp cases for which this will be used ?

Comment: That is already part of the answer.